# How can I save one Entity containing another entity so they are linked together?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple `Order` entity that contains OneToMany relation with a list of `Dishes`.

**Order** entity:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "orders")
@ToString
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
    private LocalDateTime updateDate;
    private BigDecimal totalPrice;
    private String address;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private User user;

    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "order",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<Dish> dishes;

    public Order(long id, Status status, BigDecimal totalPrice, String address, List<Dish> dishes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.status = status;
        this.creationDate = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.updateDate = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
        this.address = address;
        this.dishes = dishes;
    }
}
```

**Dish** entity:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Dish {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Category category;
    BigDecimal price;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Order order;

    public Dish(long id, String name, String description, Category category, BigDecimal price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.category = category;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
        order.addDish(this);
    }
}
```

Here I try to save Orders containg these dishes

```
Dish dish1 = new Dish(0, "Dish first", "Description of first Dish", Category.SNACKS, BigDecimal.valueOf(100));
Dish dish2 = new Dish(0, "Dish second", "Description of second Dish", Category.BURGERS, BigDecimal.valueOf(100));

List<Dish> dishes1 = Arrays.asList(dish1, dish2);
List<Dish> dishes2 = Arrays.asList(dish2);
Order order1 = new Order(0, Status.PENDING, BigDecimal.valueOf(150), "Address 1", dishes1);
Order order2 = new Order(0, Status.COMPLETED, BigDecimal.valueOf(150), "Address 2", dishes2);
```

Here is the problem, Dishes are persisted together with orders, but not associated with the `Order` Entity.
Id is null
[image]

I know I didn't set `order` field when I created dishes, but how to do this If I need save both Order and Dishes at the same time.

Comment: What you want isn't possible in your design. A dish can only belong to 1 order. You have a bi-directional relationship so you should be manage both ends. Set the `order` on the `dish` (and that should actually be a collection, or not there at all).

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you, could you please tell, why should dish have a collection of orders ( changing relationship to manyTomany ), if each instance of a dish can belong only to one order. New order - new instance.

Comment: That is not what you are doing in your test. You are creating 2 dishes (`dish1` and `dish2`) and you are assigning `dish2` to 2 orders.  But does dish really needs to know which order it belongs to? Or is it enough for the order to have a list of dishes? So does it really need to be a bi-directional relationship? And is is a ManyToOne or ManyToMany. With what you have shown here it is ManyToMany.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, yes, it was a logical mistake in the test, there will be no such a code when the app is done.
I've read that UniDirectional OneToMany association is bad as it leads to addtional SQL statements.
https://thorben-janssen.com/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong model, what id do you expect to be in dish2?
Relation between Order and Dish is NOT one-to-many, but many-to-many. Hibernate does not know what to enter in the column.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).